# Parsing issue with json

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse the json data that I get back from lastfm.
The method I'm interested in is album.search
The documentation requires there to be a search term for the album name, and an api key, which I've done here:

```
String api_key = "x";
    String url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search" + 
    "&album="
    + query
    + "&apikey="
    + api_key
    + "&format=json";
```

Then my issue was trying to iterate through the json data so I can get to the value that I wanted, in my case, name, so I made an array to loop through the json file.

```
boolean error = false;
    HttpClient httpclient = null;
    try {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse data = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        HttpEntity entity = data.getEntity();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF8");

        for ( int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject row = new JSONObject(result);

        albummatches = row.getString("albummatches");
        album = row.getString("album");
        name = row.getString("name");
        results.getJSONObject(i).get("album");
```

I have this method which returns results.

```
public JSONArray getResults() {
    return results;
}
```

Now in my other class, I'm trying to attach the name of the album to my adapter list view through this method.

```
public void ServiceComplete(AbstractService service) {
    if (!service.hasError()) {
        AlbumSearchService albumService = (AlbumSearchService)service;
        String[] result = new String[albumService.getResults().length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < albumService.getResults().length(); i++) {
            try{
                result[i] = albumService.getResults().getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                result[i] = "Error";
            }
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.album_list_cell, R.id.text, result));
    }
```

But unfortunately, when I try to run the app, and search for an album, it just stays stuck on 'searching...', and doesn't display any results in  my list view.

I don't know where I'm going wrong :( Help someone!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the JSON string from the http request? If not, try to check the content of your entity (`result`), to see if you are actually getting the content you want.

Comment: In your second code snippet, you iterate over a variable `results`, but one line before, you store the response in a  `String result`. What is `results`? Is it an array, or is it a typo and should be `result`? If `results` is a `String`, why do you iterate over `String.length`?

Comment: results is a jsonarray, and result is the json string.

Comment: Sorry, but this code is confusing. You iterate over an array that you want to fill with something you call a "row" which is (in the best case) a json string (in each iteration the same). And the line `results.getJSONObject(i).get("album");` makes no sense to me. Use a debugger and walk through your code line by line. Check the content of your variables and surely you will find the line, where your app hangs (besides some more surprises).